# [Swift]TableViewCell内に設置した関数への、cell番号の受け渡し

Tags: ios, swift

以下のtapPickView関数で該当するtableViewCellのcell番号[indexPath.row]を取得する方法が知りたいです。tableViewCellの上にtopViewが乗っており、その上にpickViewが乗っています。pickViewをtapするとtapPickView関数が起動する形になっています。

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("QuestionAndAnswerReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionAndAnswerTableViewCell        

    cell.topView.pickView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapPickView")
    cell.topView.pickView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    return cell
}

func tapPickView(){
    answerQuestionView = AnswerQuestionView()
    answerQuestionView.questionID = Array[/*ここにcell番号を入れたい*/]

    self.view.addSubview(answerQuestionView)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ご提示のコードに、追加する考え方と、アイデアを並べます。

1. `UIGestureRecognizer`のActionメソッドには、引数をつけることができる。引数は`UIGestureRecognizer`自身になる。
2. `UIGestureRecognizer`には、プロパティ`view`があって、ジェスチャーを発生したViewを取得できる。
3. `UIView`には、`Int`型のプロパティ`tag`がある。これに行番号を入れておくことで、テーブル外部から、タップした行番号を知ることができる。

---

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("QuestionAndAnswerReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionAndAnswerTableViewCell        

    cell.topView.pickView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    // var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapPickView")
    // tapは、変更を受けないので、letで宣言してかまいません。
    // セレクタに引数をつけるには、コロン「:」をつけます。
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapPickView:")
    cell.topView.pickView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    // pickViewのプロパティtagに行番号を代入する。
    cell.topView.pickView.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}

// func tapPickView(){
// アクションメソッドに、引数を追加。
func tapPickView(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    answerQuestionView = AnswerQuestionView()
    // タップしたViewを取得
    if let theView = gesture.view {
        // 行番号を取得。
        let rowNumber = theView.tag
        answerQuestionView.questionID = hogeArray[/*ここにcell番号を入れたい*/rowNumber] // はい、入りましたよ。
    }

    self.view.addSubview(answerQuestionView)
}
```

Comment: サンプルコードを事後修正しております。